# Android Downloadmanager not starting download

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, download-manager

I am trying to download a file from my server via REST.

When using `DownloadManager` nothing happens (I have put breakpoints in my server project an the server is not being reached).

When I use `AsyncHttpClient` I get the byte stream which I convert into a input stream and then to the actual file (that proves that my server actually does everything right).

I am using the same uri for the `AsyncHttpClient` and the `DownloadManager`. So I am wondering what could be wrong with the `DownloadManager`. My server returns the file as a `HTTPResponseMessage`, but even if that should be a problem for the `DownloadManager` (not sure what he is expecting), at least the function should be called.

Does anybody know what else I could try ?

As I said, with the `DownloadManager` my Server is not being reached at all (or at least the function for serving the file is not being called)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found the error. I am using `https` to connect to my server and DownloadManager has a problem with that. When I switch to `http` everything is working fine. Does DownloadManager support `https` ? I have read that some earlier versions did not support it, but the newer one should actually work fine. I think I am using the newest one but still not working ...